Comparing distplot with histplot
I try to compare the plot using distplot and histplot. With the distplot, the plot starts even before zero. Where when I use the histplot, the plot starts at zero. Here's the code comparison.
# distplot
x = house_numerical['2ndFlrSF']
sns.distplot(x, axlabel=x.name, bins = 20)
line1 = plt.axvline(x.mean(), color="k", linestyle="--", label = "mean")
line2 = plt.axvline(np.median(x), color="r", linestyle="--", label = "median")
first_legend = plt.legend(handles=[line1,line2], loc=1)
print("Median:", x.median())
print("Mean:", x.mean())
print("Std Dev:", x.std())
plt.show()

# histplot
x = house_numerical['2ndFlrSF']
sns.histplot(x, kde=True, stat='density', bins = 20)
line1 = plt.axvline(x.mean(), color="k", linestyle="--", label = "mean")
line2 = plt.axvline(np.median(x), color="r", linestyle="--", label = "median")
first_legend = plt.legend(handles=[line1,line2], loc=1)
print("Median:", x.median())
print("Mean:", x.mean())
print("Std Dev:", x.std())
plt.show()

Here's the distplot:

Here's the histplot:

How do I show the plot before zero if I want to use histplot?

kde_kws={"cut": 3})
